How can I make a single .tex file by parsing several different .json files?
For context: I'm trying to make an automated procedure that takes files from a videogame - in json format - automatically creates a manual for them.
I'll give you an example: there is a mod that adds a big robot for players to pilot and some things it can equip. The game files would be like this:
frames.json:
{
    "id": "hra_frames_antlion",
    "source": "HRA",
    "name": "Antlion",
    "stats": {
      <stats>
    },
    "traits": [
       <traits>
    ],
    "core_system": {
      <core system description>
    },
    "data_type": "frame",
    "license_id": "hra_frames_antlion",
    "license_level": 2
}

weapons.json
{
  "id": "hra_weapons_tracer_autocannon",
  "name": "Tracer Autocannon",
  "source": "HRA",
  "license": "ANTLION",
  "license_id": "hra_frames_antlion",
  "license_level": 1,
  "description": "<div>insert description here</div>",
  "mount": "Auxiliary",
  "type": "Rifle",
  "sp": "0",
  "barrage": true,
  "skirmish": true,
  "on_crit": "<div>The target gains <strong>Lock On</strong> until the end of their next turn</div>",
  "damage": [
    {
      "type": "Explosive",
      "val": 2
    }
  ],
  "range": [
    {
      "type": "Range",
      "val": 15
    }
  ]
},
{
 other weapon...
},

systems.json
<same format as weapons>

Please note that every item has two important attributes: "license_id" and "license_level"; they are needed to know which items go together and in which order they must appear in the .tex file
The .tex file I want to obtain from these JSON files, for which I already made a template, should look like this. This is pseudocode and not meant to be compilable.
\CommandForFrame %the big robot
  [<stats>]
  {<traits>}
  {<core system>}

\CommandForHeaderOfLicenseLevel{<names of items that have "license_level"=1>}

if the first license_level 1 item is a weapon
\CommandForWeapon
  {stats}
  {effects}
  {flavour text}
else if it's a system
\CommandForSystem
  {stats}
  {effects}
  {flavour text}

\CommandForHeaderOfLicenseLevel{<names of items that have "license_level"=2>}
ecc...

So in essence, I need to take items from different files, group them by their "license_id" attribute, write the command to display the item from the "frame" files, and then write the commands I have made to display the item of each other type, ordered by their "license_level" attribute
So, is there a package or functionality in LaTeX that can help me do this in a relatively simple way?
I'll post actual compilable code if you believe it's necessary, but I must warn you that I'm using a very complicated template, so the files will be very big, although they're still compilable by Overleaf s a free user.

https://ctan.org/pkg/jsonparse
